# Why does recompiling a GWT project in superdevmode result in no changes in output javascript code?

Tags: maven, gwt, compilation, gwt-super-dev-mode

I intend to debug a GWT web application in SuperDevMode that I previously debugged in DevMode in order to overcome issues where memory usage explodes using the GWT Elemental library.
Thus far I am able to successfully run the application in the browser by running with an Eclipse run configuration or `mvn gwt:run` with maven as my code server (`mvn gwt:run-codeserver`). My issue at this point is that whenever I make a change to the code and use the 'Compile' button from the 'Dev Mode On' bookmarklet, there are no resulting changes in the code in browser or the source maps. After the compile is finished, the page reloads and a dialog box says the module 'may need to be (re)compiled'. In order to refresh the code in the browser, I have to relaunch the code server. The pom.xml for my project is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
<!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>mega-app</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.6.0</gwtVersion>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Server protocol -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-elemental</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- URL that should be automatically opened in the GWT shell (gwt:run). -->
                <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                <module>com.company.App</module>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                <i18nMessagesBundle>com.company.web.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                <compileSourcesArtifacts>
                    <compileSourcesArtifact>com.company:protocol</compileSourcesArtifact>
                </compileSourcesArtifacts>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>  <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
                    </buildCommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance for any details I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.ltgt.net/how-does-gwts-super-dev-mode-work/) is a post from Thomas Broyer explaining the SuperDevMode Workflow.

In your Network Tab under DevTools of your browser, did you have the "gwtSourcemap.json" request with Status Ok when the compilation finished?

BTW, if you make changes on the server part (not GWT client part), you have to restart server on the normal DevMode.

Hope it helps.